# Why Rails doesn't print output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need your help: I have a simple application in Rails and I don't know why it doesn't print attributes on the screen with whatever model I am working on.
For example I have a "Account" model with attributes "first_name", "last_name", "username", etc .. and 4 entries inserted for users in the database table Account.
These are the controller and views files:

```
    class PublicController < ApplicationController
    
    def main
       @users = Account.all
    end

    end
```

And this is the view file (public/main.html.erb):

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
        <% user.first_name %>
        <% user.last_name %>
        <% user.username %>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't print anything but if I change the second line of the view file with:

```
<% if user.first_name? %> first_name exists <% end %>
```

The output is 4 times: first_name exists.
So why it doesn't print the attributes first_name, last_name, username?

Comment: You need `<%= ... %>` in ERB to print. Otherwise your code is only evaluated.

Comment: Your second try prints something because is combined with "raw" HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [ERB](https://apidock.com/ruby/ERB) the `<% %>` tag evaluates Ruby code but does not print the output, where as `<%= %>` does print the output

This will correct the issue

```
<%= user.first_name %>
<%= user.last_name %>
<%= user.username %>
```